# Hibernate - table doesn't exist during deletion

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, innodb

So I am trying to delete a hibernate entity from the database but it's giving me back an error saying the table doesn't exist. It doesn't seem to have any problem finding the entity and saving changes or creating new entities - it only complains when deleting an entity.

This code results in an error saying the table doesn't exist.

```
try
    {
        Transaction txn = s.beginTransaction();
        Resource r = (Resource) s.get(Resource.class, rid);
        s.delete(r);
        txn.commit();
    }
```

This code pulls the entity out of the database and prints the ID with no problems.

```
try
    {
        Transaction txn = s.beginTransaction();
        Resource r = (Resource) s.get(Resource.class, rid);
        System.out.println(r.getId());
        txn.commit();
    }
```

Console output

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        resource0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        resource0_.bookable as bookable2_1_0_,
        resource0_.description as descript3_1_0_,
        resource0_.name as name4_1_0_ 
    from
        resources resource0_ 
    where
        resource0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        resources_resources 
    where
        resources_id=?
2016-02-07 02:27:13.831  WARN 8396 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2016-02-07 02:27:13.831 ERROR 8396 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'bargaink_megtest.resources_resources' doesn't exist
2016-02-07 02:27:13.831  INFO 8396 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

I have no idea how this could happen when it can quite clearly see the table when adding new entities and updating existing entities. Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Is this going in same session or in different sessions?

Comment: @KenBekov its the same code I just changed that one line to test if it was getting the entity back which it was

Comment: Did you try to delete entity with HQL query?

Comment: @KenBekov Just tried HQL, still giving the same error back :/

Comment: Select and delete generated SQLs pointed to different tables. Check the class. Is it possible you have 2 different classes (imports)? Check any interceptors which might generate SQL

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that maybe you would be that your `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is set to `create`. If it's so, then please change it.

change:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

*Kindly post your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file if it the above solution doesn't work. We'll dig deeper into your code then.*